# Message Box is not appearing in simple compare text box strings program

Tags: c#

very beginner programmer here. I am creating an application that displays 2 text boxes. The information is entered via barcode scanner. When both text boxes are filled it will then either show a green checkmark or show a message box error that explains that the barcodes do not match.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //label1 = your tick
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if same, show, if different, show message box error
            if (string.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, true) == 0)
                label2.Visible = true;
            else
                label2.Visible = false;
            if (string.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, false) == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Barcodes Do Not Match")
                //label3.Visible = true;
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if same, show, if different, show message box error
            if (string.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, true) == 0)
                label2.Visible = true;

            else
                label2.Visible = false;
            if (string.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, false) == 0)
                //label3.Visible = false;
             MessageBox.Show("Barcodes Do Not Match");

                //label3.Visible = true;
```

If I do something like this:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)


 {
        //if same, show, if different, show message box error
        if (string.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, true) == 0)
            label2.Visible = true;

        else
          //  label2.Visible = false;
       // if (string.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, false) == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Barcodes Do Not Match");
        //label3.Visible = false;
```

I get the text box not filling completely from the barcode and the message box kind of pops up but not before moving the cursor out of the text box.

I've tried a few different things. With this coding I'm getting the check mark and no problems with the text entered(which was getting cut off before) but still no Message Box. I'm pretty new to coding in general so any help is much appreciated. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison for the message box will only pass if the strings are the same so you aren't seeing the message box. You should use some braces to do both your expected actions from the same block

```
//if same, show, if different, show message box error
if (string.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, true) == 0)
{
     label2.Visible = true;
}
else
{
     label2.Visible = false;
     MessageBox.Show("Barcodes Do Not Match")
}
```

Comment: So when I use that a message box still does not show up and when I scan the barcode it only scans 1 or 2 characters of the barcode and then stops. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: I don't know anything about the barcode libraries you are using.  I would open another ticket specifically for that.  As far as the message box goes if, when the textchanged event fires, the dialog box will show.  So something about the rest of your code is not causing the textchanged event to fire.

Comment: Hmm. Alright I'll do that. Strange because I don't have any more code than that, other than a button to close the program. Thank you for the help.